# Why the packages object-hash and crypto / hashlib return different values for sha1?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, hashlib, object-hash

I have a javascript frontend which compares two `object-hash` sha1 hashes in order to determine if an input has changed (in which case a processing pipeline needs to be reran).

I started building a python interface to interact with the same backend which uses `hashlib` for the sha1 generation, but unfortunately the two functions return different hash values even though the inputs are the same.

I managed to produce the same hash values as `hashlib` using `crypto`, which means that the issue arises from `object-hash`.

**hashlib**

```py
import json
import hashlib

data = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2',
    'key3': 'value3',
}; 

json_data = json.dumps(data, separators=(',', ':')).encode('utf-8')

hash = hashlib.sha1()
hash.update(json_data)
print(hash.hexdigest())

# outputs f692755b3c38bc6b0dc376d775db8b07d6d5f256
```

**crypto**

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

const data = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2',
    key3: 'value3',
};

const stringData = JSON.stringify(data)

const shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1')
shasum.update(stringData)
console.log(shasum.digest('hex'));

// (same as hashlib) outputs f692755b3c38bc6b0dc376d775db8b07d6d5f256
```

**object-hash** (Tested with and without stringifying with no success)

```js
const data = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2',
    key3: 'value3',
};

const stringData = JSON.stringify(data)


const objectHash = require('object-hash');
console.log(objectHash.sha1(stringData));

// outputs b5b0a100d7852748fe2e35bf00eeb536ad2d17d1
```

I saw in `object-hash` docs that the package is using `crypto` so it doesn't make sense for the two outputs to be different.

How can I make `object-hash` and `hashlib`/`crypto` all produce the same sha1 value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `object-hash` prefixes the variable for hashing with its type. In the case of strings I needed to add `string:{string_length}:` to the hash stream.

```py
hash = hashlib.sha1()

hash.update(f'string:{len(json_data)}:'.encode('utf-8')) # The line in question

hash.update(json_data)
res = hash.hexdigest()
print(res)
```

Having done that, the hashes produced by `hashlib` and `crypto` are the same as those of `object-hash`.

*Note:* This is not documented and I had to look through the source code to find exactly how to prefix strings in particular. Other types have different prefixes.